# asp.net web application fails to recognize user identity

Tags: asp.net, authentication, web-applications, identity

We have a web application and it uses System.Web.UI.Page.User.Identity to determine who the current user is. We are experiencing an intermittent problem, where a user is not recognized (their identity is blank or empty). Anonymous authentication is disabled so I don't see how they can fully access the web application without it recognizing who they are. This happens like once a month for half a day, and then it fixes itself. So it's really hard to diagnose but I would really like to track down the issue. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: What kind of authentication mode are you using? From web.config: <authentication mode="??">

Comment: There is no authentication section in the web.config! Here are some related contents:

<section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />

and 

<authorization><allow users="*" /></authorization>

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have anonymous authentication turned off & windows authentication enabled for the application in IIS.